# LEFT OUTER JOIN With Condition In Third Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

**[SQL Fiddle Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a333/4)**

Brilliant SQL Writers,

I am trying to get all dates in a certain range (stored as records in T1), and the sum of values of records in a related table (T2). However, some of the records in T2 will be filtered out by the value of a field in a third table (T3).

Assuming tables like this:

```
TABLE T1
| MonthYearKey |
|==============|
| 201401       |
| 201402       |
| 201403       |
| 201404       |
| 201405       |
| 201406       |

TABLE T2
| MonthYearKey | NextKey | MyValue |
|==============+=========+=========|
| 201402       | 6       | 10      |
| 201403       | 6       | 10      |
| 201404       | 6       | 10      |
| 201402       | 8       | 10      |
| 201403       | 8       | 10      |
| 201404       | 8       | 10      |
| 201401       | 10      | 10      |
| 201402       | 10      | 10      |
| 201406       | 10      | 10      |

TABLE T3
| NextKey | IsValid |
|=========+=========|
| 6       | 1       |
| 8       | 1       |
| 10      | 0       |
```

The SQL I am running is:

```
SELECT T1.MonthYearKey, SUM(ISNULL(T2.MyValue, 0)) AS SumOfValues
FROM T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.MonthYearKey = T2.MonthYearKey
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 ON T2.NextKey = T3.NextKey
WHERE ISNULL(T3.IsValid, 1) = 1
GROUP BY T1.MonthYearKey
```

The output I expected is:

```
| MonthYearKey | SumOfValues |
|==============+=============|
| 201401       | 0           |
| 201402       | 20          |
| 201403       | 20          |
| 201404       | 20          |
| 201405       | 0           |
| 201406       | 0           |
```

However, as you can see in the SQL Fiddle, the 201401 and 201406 months are dropped out of the results altogether. I assume this is because it selected the records with NextKey = 10, which then was filtered out by the IsValid = 0.

**QUESTION:** How can I get ALL of the MonthYearKeys, even those that are currently being filtered out in my SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.MonthYearKey, SUM(ISNULL(T2.MyValue, 0)) AS SumOfValues
FROM T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT T2.MyValue, T2.MonthYearKey
    FROM T2
    JOIN T3 ON T2.NextKey = T3.NextKey AND ISNULL(T3.IsValid, 1) = 1
  ) T2 ON T1.MonthYearKey = T2.MonthYearKey
GROUP BY T1.MonthYearKey
```

Try here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a333/26

**EDIT**:

Without nested query:

```
SELECT T1.MonthYearKey, SUM(ISNULL(T2.MyValue, 0)) AS SumOfValues
  FROM T2
  JOIN T3 ON T2.NextKey = T3.NextKey AND T3.IsValid = 1
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN T1 ON T1.MonthYearKey = T2.MonthYearKey
GROUP BY T1.MonthYearKey
```

Without nested query by changing `JOIN` precedence:

```
SELECT T1.MonthYearKey, SUM(ISNULL(T2.MyValue, 0)) AS SumOfValues
FROM T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (T2 JOIN T3 ON T2.NextKey = T3.NextKey AND T3.IsValid = 1)
  ON T1.MonthYearKey = T2.MonthYearKey
GROUP BY T1.MonthYearKey
```

SQL Fidle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a333/45

Answer (score 4):

When you apply the filter in the `where` clause, you lose the rows -- including the column used for `group by`.

Instead, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT T1.MonthYearKey,
       COALESCE(SUM(case when t3.isvalid is null or t3.isvalid = 1
                         then T2.MyValue
                    end), 0
               ) as SumOfValues
FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.MonthYearKey = T2.MonthYearKey LEFT OUTER JOIN T3
     ON T2.NextKey = T3.NextKey
GROUP BY T1.MonthYearKey;
```

Comment: I see that you used the COALESCE function to make sure that all months have a value of zero if they have no results. Why did you choose COALESCE instead of ISNULL (I've not used COALESCE before)? Does COALESCE have any performance implications since it is evaluated multiple times, or reliability implications since results could change (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: I prefer `coalesce()` because it is the ANSI standard function.  However, `isnull()` is often preferred in SQL Server, because (in my opinion) SQL Server has a broken implementation of `coalesce()`.  So, feel free to use either one.